# Yii-Custom Search combobox

Tags: php, yii

I have a filed status in database that can store 0 or 1. 0=Inactive and 1=Active. When I create a combobox in yii, admin.php file it searches properly but the text that appears in combobox is 0 and 1, but I to see In-Active and Active, but in option values it should be 0 and 1.
here is my code...

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'cities-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
'id',
'country.countryname'=>array('name'=>'countryid', 'value'=>'$data->country->countryname', 'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Countries::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'countryname')), 'id', 'countryname')),

'cityname',
'citycode',
'citystatus'=>array('name'=>'citystatus', 'value'=>'$data->setCityStatus() . $data->getCityStatus($data->citystatus)', 'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Cities::model()->findAll(array()), 'citystatus', 'citystatus')),
'citycoords',

array(
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'template'=> ($iHasFullAccess == 1 ? '{view}{update}{delete}' :  '{view}') ,
),
),
)); 
?>
```

Comment: paste your yii code which contains your combobox logic

Comment: look at the view code...admin.php

Comment: functions getCityStatus() and setCityStatus() i wrote to create an array of status in model here is the code public function setCityStatus()
 {
  $this->aCityStatus = array('In-Active', 'Active');
 }
 
 public function getCityStatus($iIndex)
 {
  return($this->aCityStatus[$iIndex]);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your citystatus option in CgridView list as below

```
'citystatus'=>array('name'=>'citystatus', 'value'=>'Cities::getCityStatus($data->citystatus)', 'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Cities::model()->findAll(array()), 'citystatus', 'citystatus')),
```

Change your getCityStatus function in your Cities model as below

```
function getCityStatus($index){
  $status = array('Inactive','Active');
  return $status[$index];
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want the values "Active" and "inactive" in dropdown, this is the main issue, the search combobox shows value 1 and 0 but i want to see string values.

Comment: Then you have to make custom function in your model and modify array of findAll and then pass on to listData

Answer (score 0):

in your CGridView configure your column like this:

```
'citystatus'=>array(
   'name'=>'citystatus',
   'value'=>'$data->citystatus == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive"', 
   'filter'=> array(0 => 'Inactive', 1 => 'Active')),
```

Comment: please answer this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010848/yii-search-dropdown-for-parent-of-parent

Comment: Its a closed question, no one can reply, also why don't you choose an answer for this question?

Comment: there is no answer for this question, plz tell me if u know

Comment: I just pudated my answer to be more explicit, let me know it is not working

Answer (score 0):

After reading this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Add the following, if it is a model:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\citystatus;
```

And later in the datagrid

```
>    'columns' => [
>         ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
>         .....................,
>         [
>             'attribute' => 'deviceState',
>             'value' => 'deviceStateList.Description',
>             'label' => 'Device State',
>             'filter'=> ArrayHelper::map(Citystatus::find()->all(), 'RecordID', 'CityName'),
>         ],
```

HTH